# Organizing workflow with Mercurial and Netbeans (+ bitbucket.org?)

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, workflow, bitbucket

I've never worked with any version control systems before. Now I'm trying to learn Mercurial, but I'm confused (I've already read about 10-15 articles + hginit.com). I don't know how to organize the workflow.

I have a testing server and a production server. I work from my office computer and from my home laptop. I make changes directly on the testing server, and every week or so copy new code to my production server. I also need wiki/issues/etc. pretty much everything bitbucket.org has. I know that's a bad way of doing things.

Is there any tutorial or articles on how to organize the workflow? I'd also appreciate any schemes/sketches describing the process.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify. Are you saying you want all the things bitbucket has, but you can't use it? Or are you asking if you should be using bitbucket?

Comment: Well, seems like I want to use bitbucket, but I'm not sure how to connect everything to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit: Changed based on comments]

> Using Bitbucket

Once you have created an account.

1. You should be able to create a repo with an appropriate url. Then you can clone it to create a local repository.
   Check out [**getting started**](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Getting+Started+with+Bitbucket).
2. See the following to [**push the updates to BitBucket**](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Pushing+Updates+to+a+Bitbucket+Repository).
3. BitBucket comes with [**very extensive documentation**](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Bitbucket+Documentation+Home).

Also there are, other useful tools to work with BitBucket:

1. [**BitbucketExtension**](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BitbucketExtension) that allows you to use command line for a number of operations.
2. [Using Mercurial Queues and bitbucket.org](http://ches.nausicaamedia.com/articles/technogeekery/using-mercurial-queues-and-bitbucket-org)

> Organizing workflow

You will have to evolve a workflow that suits you. In your case, it looks like you have a testing server and production server.

So , you can setup two repositories, one for the testing server ad one for production. You can make push to testing server automatic so that you can test out the changes immediately. You can tag releases that are then pushed to production server.

1. Your local repo can be used to publish changes to testing server.
2. You can push the approved changes, tagged to BitBucket repository.